# Use of show() function in Matplotlib library

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and have a very basic question. 
In the matplot library we have `show()` function. I just want to know what is the benefit of using `show()` function.

For ex. if we have multiple statements such as

```
plt.scatter(XX,YY)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()     #3rd statement, is it necessary?
```

We can plot a scatter plot and can superimpose plot on it just by executing these two statements. Whether we write the 3rd statement i.e. `plt.show()` hardly matters. Does it matter? When do we use `plt.show()`.

Please explain. Thank You.

Comment: I am afraid, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that i understand your question exactly.

'plt.show()' function do visualize your plot.
And plt.scatter() and plt.plot() can't visualize its data independently.
But you can do it, if you use jupyter-notebook with '%matplotlib inline' command.
It helps to show plots without 'plt.show()' command.

Comment: I am able to visualize both plt.scatter() and plt.plot() without using plt.show() in Spyder. What is the use of plt.show() then?

Comment: Spyder tool also helps you can see the graph without show() function.

Comment: You can try the same python code at pure console (powershell or ubuntu bash) and you may see the difference.